# Synthesize an integer key for a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with data grouped by 2 columns `key1` and `key2`. What I would like to achieve is to get a single integer key enumerating over all present pairs of `(key1, key2)`. E.g. to a dataset that looks like this:

```
    key1  key2  data
    A     1     ...
    A     1     ...
    A     2     ...
    C     1     ...
    B     1     ...
    B     1     ...
    C     1     ...
```

I would like to have an `id` column added that would enumerate things:

```
  id  key1  key2    data
  1     A     1     ...
  1     A     1     ...
  2     A     2     ...
  3     C     1     ...
  4     B     1     ...
  4     B     1     ...
  3     C     1     ...
```

I don't care the order in which `id`s are distributed, I only need to be able to subset the table based on single number, not a pair of key columns. How can this be achieved?

Comment: `x<-unique(dt,by=c("key1","key2"))[,id:=.I]; dt[x,id:=i.id,on=c("key1","key2")]`

Comment: `setkey(dt, key1, key2); dt[,id:=rleid(key1, key2) ,]`

Comment: @MichaelChirico isn't `on` a 1.9.5 dev data.table feature? I'm using 1.9.4

Comment: @Khashaa `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rleid"` - does this require a specific package?

Comment: in that case ``setkey(dt,key1,key2); dt[unique(dt)[,id:=.I],id:=i.id]`` should work

Comment: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'i..I' not found`, ``.I`` doesn't help either =(

Comment: I was cheating, see edit.

Comment: Seems to work just fine now! Thanks, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

You could do either:

```
dt[unique(dt,by=c("key1","key2"))[,id:=.I],id:=i.id,on=c("key1","key2")]
```

Or (as gracefully pointed out by @Khashaa in the comments; in fact, this is probably the way favored by @Arun, given the [function was created for cases just like this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/686))

```
setkey(dt,key1,key2)[,id:=rleid(key1,key2)]
```

Note that the output from the second will be different from the first, in general--the latter will be sorted by `key1` and `key2`; this isn't necessarily the case for the former. This may or may not be more efficient, depending on your data. If you want to force the first case to be sorted, simply amend to `[order(key1,key2),id:=.I]`